# How to Use Docker (or alternative) as Test Environment

Tags: testing, docker, virtual-machine

As part of my job I evaluate many software and applications. 
I need to have an environment that is easy to clean (so the previous apps are not bloating my system) and always light.
One idea is to create isolated environments (either by Docker or Virtual machines) and fire up a new environment every time I need to start over with new software to evaluate.

Questions:
1.Does Docker support this? Can I use it to create new environment every few days and test software in it?
2. If not, which VM system would be suitable for this particular need?

Thanks

Comment: Docker or Vagrant sound perfect for what you are describing.

Comment: Ok good.. Thanks. Just to confirm, I mean 3rd party software which I don't have the code for.. Only the executable files..

Comment: I don't see the purpose in container-izing a binary other than to isolate the environment that it executes in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what all the Continuous Integration systems do: get fresh code, build your project and run tests inside the freshly created container. This is how clean testing is done nowadays. So Docker fits perfectly your needs.

Each fresh container is a clean environment where you can run your tests in. Then you can parse the result and remove the container, for example `docker run --rm -it my-image ./tests.sh`

Comment: This sounds awesome for my other need (testing in-house apps). But do you see Docker (or similar products) suitable for testing 3rd party applications, which I only get the executable files ?

Comment: Forgot to mention you for my previous reply.. I'm new to SO : )
@n2o

Comment: Hm why not if it is not too complicated. In my opinion containers (or similar) are the best way to test applications. But I agree that it is very unusual to test a binary